# how to redirect using Rest API to HTML page in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I have created login api, i want to redirect to
homepage after login successfully.
code:

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  var session = req.session;
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;
  User.findOne({
    username: username,
    password: password
  }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).json("Error");
    }
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json("User Not Found");
    }
    session.isLogin = true;
    return res.status(200).json("Login Successfully!!!");
    res.redirect('/public/modules/login/homepage.html');
  });
});
```

Comment: `res.redirect` works only `GET` requests you can't redirect `POST` request

Comment: so,can i use as, res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/modules/login/homepage.html'));

Comment: No you can't, if you do this you will receive html file text in body of your `httprequest` response

Comment: so, how i give the link of html page in route api.

Comment: share your front-end code and will help to figure it out

Comment: my Controller file:$scope.submit=function(){
                 $http({
                method : "POST",
                url : "http://localhost:3000/api/login",
                data :{"username":$scope.login.username,"password":$scope.login.password}
                }).then(function mySucces(response) {
                  alert('success');
                  url:"https://www.google.com";
                $scope.myWelcome = response.success;
                }, function myError(response) {
                $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
               });
                 }

Comment: html file :<md-content  ng-controller="logController" layout="row" layout-align="space-around" layout-padding="layout-padding" ng-cloak="ng-cloak" class="md-content">
      <md-card flex="flex" flex-gt-sm="50" flex-gt-md="50" class="card">
          <md-toolbar class="md-warn ">
              <div class="md-toolbar-tools"><h2 class="md-flex">Login</h2></div>
          </md-toolbar>
          <form name="loginForm" id="loginForm" novalidate>
              <md-input-container class="md-block">
                <label>User Name</label>

Comment: <input type="text" required name="username" ng-model="login.username">
                <div ng-messages="loginForm.username.$error">
                  <div ng-message="required">Please enter your User name</div>
                </div>
              </md-input-container>             
              </md-input-container>        
              <md-input-container class="md-block">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" ng-model="login.password" ng-minlength="3" required />

Comment: <div ng-messages="loginForm.password.$error" ng-show="loginForm.password.$touched || loginForm.$submitted">
                <div ng-message="required">Please enter your password</div>
                    <div ng-message="minlength">Passwords must be 3 characters.</div>
                </div>              
               </md-input-container>
                <br>
                <md-button class="md-warn md-hue-2"  ng-click="submit()" 
                ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid">Login</md-button>

Comment: <p class="  margin right-align medium-small" align="right">
               <a ui-sref="forgot" class="btn btn-xl">forgot</a>
               </p>
               </form>
            </md-card>
 </md-content>

Comment: did you get the answer of your question? If yes, then please share.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you use `angular.js` redirect should happen on client side. You should return success status code from backend and in front-end use ui-router `$state.go('home')` method see this article to get started in ui-router: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router

```
$scope.submit = function() {
  $http({
    method: "POST",
    url: "localhost:3000/api/login";,
    data: {
      "username": $scope.login.username,
      "password": $scope.login.p‌​ assword
    }
  }).then(function mySucces(response) {
    alert('success');
    $state.go('home');
  }, function myError(response) {
    $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
  });
}
```